# Laravel 5 composer update to latest v5 fails

Tags: laravel, composer-php

2 months ago i created a simple app in Laravel 5.

Today i tried to do a composer update and it fails.

The message at the end says:

```
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing dflydev/markdown (~1.0)
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing erusev/parsedown (~1.0)



  [Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]
    Problem 1
      - Installation request for laravel/framework ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/frame
  work[5.0.x-dev].
      - laravel/framework 5.0.x-dev requires symfony/console 2.6.* -> no matching packa
  ge found.
    Problem 2
      - laravel/framework 5.0.x-dev requires symfony/console 2.6.* -> no matching packa
  ge found.
      - illuminate/html 5.0.x-dev requires illuminate/http ~5.0 -> satisfiable by larav
  el/framework[5.0.x-dev].
      - Installation request for illuminate/html 5.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by illuminate
  /html[5.0.x-dev].
  Potential causes:
   - A typo in the package name
   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-
  stability setting
     see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for mo
  re details.
  Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common prob
  lems.
```

I replaced my `composer.json` file from the latest i found on Github (laravel) but the same message shows up.

I also run `composer clearcache` several times.

Running a `composer install` brings the app back to life by reading the existing `composer.lock` file.

**composer.json file:**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "~5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

After deleting vandor directory and running composer update i get:

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Application::detectEnvir
onment() must be an instance of Closure, array given, called in C:\UniServerZ\www\sicktrac
k\bootstrap\environment.php on line 18 and defined in C:\UniServerZ\www\sicktrack\vendor\l
aravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php on line 299
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an erro
r
```

Comment: When you say "`composer install` brings the app back to life" does that mean everything is alright now?

Comment: No it means that i am back to my previous working situation because composer install used the composer.lock file....If i make composer update it will mess my composer.lock file and app doesnt run..So i revert the composer.lock and json file and make composer install to make my app work

Comment: I see. Does [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6297) help?

Comment: No because i want to be able to run composer update and get the latest build of laravel 5

Comment: Have you even clicked on the link? It says to set the global minimum stability to `dev`.

Comment: !! I didnt see that "this" was a link ..:) i already have the minimum stability to dev....The fresh composer.json that i took from github/laravel has it...

Comment: Hmm okay. No idea if it helps but you could try to delete the whole vendor directory and run `composer update` again.

Comment: @lukasgeiter did that but now i get another error. Please see my updated question at the end

Comment: This sounds like the contents of your `bootstrap` directory (and maybe other stuff too) are outdated. Either try to fix it by hand using [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/develop) or make a fresh install and migrate your code.